# Alteração de rota em projeto ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Adicionei um middleware de autenticação em um projeto Razor Pages. O código do Program.cs está aqui:

```
using AppleStoreIdentity.Database;
using AppleStoreIdentity.Repository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var configuration = builder.Configuration;

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDeviceRepository, DeviceRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepository>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppleDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppleDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
})
    .AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "AspNetCore.Cookies";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.LoginPath = "/Login";
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Também adicionei a anotação [Authorize] na PageModel da página Edit, que é a rota que eu quero colocar a autenticação.

```
[Authorize]
public class EditDeviceModel : PageModel
{
...
```

Quando eu tento acessar essa página, a aplicação redireciona para uma rota /Account/Login, o que eu acredito que seja o padrão. Acontece que eu não tenho uma página /Account/Login no projeto. Todas as páginas foram incluídas na pasta Pages, já que o projeto é apenas um CRUD simples para a faculdade.

Como eu consigo alterar de forma eficaz a rota padrão de Login para a pasta Pages/Login?

O que eu já tentei foi colocar o código `options.LoginPath = "/Pages/Login";` nas configurações do Identity na classe Program, mas mesmo assim, ele acaba redirecionando para a pasta /Account/Login.

Answer (score -3):

Para alcançar este objetivo, você precisa alterar o `DefaultChallengeScheme` como segue:

```
options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
```